# What is the correct order of operations for expression $\sin\frac{\pi}{2} n$

Tags: notation

What is the correct order of operations for $\sin\frac{\pi}{2}  n$? Two options that come to mind are $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}  n)$ and  $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) \cdot n$.

Are there any rules for this and what is the correct version?

Comment: If I had to write something like this, I would use parenthesis to clarify. In this case both interpretations are possible, and ultimately you would have to interpret it based on the context. On the other hand, perhaps the first interpretations makes a bit more sense, since $\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)\cdot n$ is equal to just $n$.

Comment: What about $\sin\left(\frac\pi{2n}\right)$ ? ;-)

Comment: @MattiP. it was written like that in a part of my homework instructions, I would have used parentheses as well

Answer (score 0):

Usually the multiplication is done first, then you take the value of a function, then addition (if there is one). That is

$$ \sin xy = \sin (xy)$$
but
$$ \sin x+y = (\sin x) +y $$

However, if you have any doubts whether it will be clear, use the parentheses.

Comment: Functions have the highest priority IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Unless some context justifies it, there is no reason to write $\sin\frac\pi2$ rather than $1$.

An unambigous notation is

$$\sin\frac{n\pi}2.$$